# Building a template based NLG system to generate a report from data

Tags: natural-language-processing, long-short-term-memory, bert

I am a newbie to NLP and NLG. I am tasked to develop a system to generate a report based on a given data table. The structure of the report and the flow is predefined. I have researched on several existing python libraries like BERT, SimpleNLG but they don't seem to fit my need.

For example:
input_data(country = 'USA', industry = 'Coal', profit = '4m', trend = 'decline')
output: The coal industry in USA declined by 4m.

The input data array can be different combinations (and dynamic) based on a data table. I would like to know if  there is any python package available, or any resource discussing a practical approach for this.

Comment: Welcome to AI Stack Exchange. This seems more like a task for a very simple templating system, rather than anything requiring complex language models. If you don't think that is the case, can you give a few more examples of input and output that capture the range of possible topics and output styles that you need to generate?

Comment: I am also looking for a template-based approach like you. Could you please help me with this; since it's been a year you have asked this question, I am skeptical that must have built one.